# Formatting issues / missing data when multiple commands use Select-Object within a script

Tags: powershell, select, output

I've run into a problem with my PowerShell scripts where I am "losing" output that was going to the console, or being redirected.    After much legwork, I simplified it down to an easily documented example of the problem.

Place the following single line in a script (test1.ps1), and invoke it from a basic PowerShell command window:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_share  | select name, path
```

and you will likely get two columns of output similar to the following:

```
PS C:\Users\me\temp> ./test1.ps1

name                                    path
----                                    ----
ADMIN$                                  C:\Windows
C$                                      C:\
IPC$
Users                                   C:\Users
```

but now, create a two line script (test2.ps1) like this, and run it in the same manner:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_share | select name
Get-WmiObject win32_share | select name, path
```

and observe the output gets mangled:

```
PS C:\Users\me\temp> ./test2.ps1

name
----
ADMIN$
C$
IPC$
Users
ADMIN$
C$
IPC$
Users
```

The two commands are actually run , but the second call gets "squeezed" into the output of the first.   It lost its second column, and its header and spacing.

This really seems to be a problem of the "first" output not properly "closing out", because it really doesn't seem to matter what the second line is if it pipes into another select statement.

As an aside, my original lines looked a bit more like this:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_share | select name, path | Write-Output
Get-WmiObject win32_share | select name | Write-Output
```

So that from a powershell prompt, I could direct the output wherever I desired using redirection

```
PS C:\Users\me\temp\> ./test2.ps1 > ./outfile.txt
```

As stated, actual case is more complez than this, but at this point, I just want to get a understanding of what is happening.

Bug?  Or failure to comprehend on my part?

Comment: It's kind of an idiosyncrasy in the way default formatting works.  Jefferey Snover explains it here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/04/30/586973.aspx

Comment: thank you  for the quick post, this got me back on track.     I know SO frowns on links, but speed does help.   I'll probably do a comprehensive answer based on this

Comment: Great article reference.  Also interesting the author of the blog ( team) basically calls it out as a bug at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [link from mjolinor](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/04/30/586973.aspx) explains it in more detail but PowerShell is trying to group your outputs together here. An important line from the post states:

> If the first Object has 2 properties, you'll get a 2 column table even if all the other objects in the stream have 10 properties.

In the following example

```
Get-WmiObject win32_share | select name
Get-WmiObject win32_share | select name, path
```

When the seconds command has run the output from the previous did not have that property so PowerShell, more specifically `Out-Default` drops it in output in order to make all the output synchronous.

I would be more curious what your real code was that was creating this issue. Like [expirat001](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31441419/3829407) shows you can convert the output to string and this won't happen since they are no longer objects. Be careful doing so as you can lose the original objects this way. Either way the data is not lost. Just not being displayed the way you expect.

Referring back to the example from before we can pretend the first line didn't have a path property. Calling it from `select` anyway would just create the null column but would allow the other output to be displayed.

```
# In this next command "path" is not a valid property but PowerShell will create the column anyway
Get-WmiObject win32_share | select name, path 
Get-WmiObject win32_share | select name, path
```

This is cheating but you could sent one of the commands to a different output stream.

```
Get-WmiObject win32_share | select name
Get-WmiObject win32_share | select name, path | Out-Host
```

Comment: No, the main problem is that the entire output of the script (that consists of two lines) is treated as sequence of `PSObject`s piped into `Out-Default` hus forming one table, not two.

Comment: @vesper I don't understand what I said here that is wrong? I didn't say that two tables were formed?

Comment: Okay, probably I misunderstood you in this, but I didn't see you mentioning what is actually happening with the data, and where. Maybe you should revise what wording do you use, or maybe I should have slept better.

Comment: My real code was really so far from the above it just wouldn't make much sense here.   It basically started out as why am I missing entire chunks of output that worked when run off one by one.   Only after hours of code reduction did I realize that it was an output problem and even then it took me a while to realize it was the case where I had an output with 2 columns then 3.    Then I needed to generalize it enough so it could be reproduced by anyone.

Comment: @dave_the_dev that ok I was just curious. Sometimes people present X issue for actual Y problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-WmiObject win32_share | select name | ft
Get-WmiObject win32_share | select name, path | ft


Get-WmiObject win32_share | ft name
Get-WmiObject win32_share | ft name, path
```

Comment: The code is correct, but an explanation could really help.

Answer (score 1):

The [link from mjolinor](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/04/30/586973.aspx) indeed explains a lot, the main issue here is that you are launching a script via `& ./test2.ps1` and the output of **this** command is piped into `Out-Default`. In turn, `Out-Default` sees a set of `PSObject`s generated by `Select-Object` cmdlets, and examining the first object (this is the first object returned by `Get-WmiObject win32_share | select name`) it sees that it has only one property "name" and subsequently formats a table out of resultant objects gathering only `name` property out of all of them.

To circumvent, use `ft` or `Format-Table` cmdlet to turn the output of each line into a sequence of `String`s and not `PSObject`s, this way when the script's output will be piped into `Out-Default`, it will pass strings through unprocessed.