# Getting 2 or more data tables from multiple SQL Queries with different table, columns, rows using PowerShell in one runtime

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Seeking for your advises and suggestions for my issue in running multiple SQL queries using PowerShell.

I'm running two different SQL queries.

First query:

```
SELECT primary_replica FROM sys.dm_hadr_availability_group_states
```

Second query:

```
SELECT [member_name] AS [Name]
      ,[member_type_desc] AS[Type]
      ,[member_state_desc] AS [State]
      ,[Quorum Vote] = CASE WHEN [number_of_quorum_votes]=1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
FROM [master].[sys].[dm_hadr_cluster_members]
```

These return different results. Different no. of rows, columns and the table itself.

The first query result: it only returns the primary replica; 1 column.

The second query result: it returns the replica name, cluster type, its state and quorum vote.

My question is that, I'm planning to use these 2 data tables for me to use it as an e-mail verification, but everytime I call it inside PowerShell the second data table always gives me an empty value. The reason is because they're having different results. So how can I get the results I wanted with changing the SQL query in PS?

I already tried closing the SQL connection before running the second query but it still throws me an empty table on my second query.

EDIT: Added PS script.

Using `Invoke-Sqlcmd` cmdlet:

```bsh
$query = @("SELECT [member_name] AS [Name] ,[member_type_desc] AS[Type] ,[member_state_desc] AS [State] ,[Quorum Vote] = Case WHEN [number_of_quorum_votes]=1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END FROM [master].[sys].[dm_hadr_cluster_members]", "SELECT primary_replica FROM sys.dm_hadr_availability_group_states")

foreach ($querys in $query) {
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $querys -Database master -ServerInstance VD104855
}
```

Second script (.Net approach):

```bsh
Function Run-Query {
    param([string[]]$queries)
    Begin {
        $SQLServer = 'localhost'
        $Database = 'db'
        $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $Database; Integrated Security = True"
    }
    Process {
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $queries.count; $i++) {
            $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

            # Use the current index ($i) to get the query
            $SqlCmd.CommandText = $queries[$i]

            $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
            $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
            $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
            $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
            $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)

            $DataSet.Tables
        }
    }
    End {
        $SqlConnection.Close()
    }
}

$queries = @()

$queries += 
"SELECT [member_name] AS [Name]
    ,[member_type_desc] AS[Type]
    ,[member_state_desc] AS [State]
    ,[Quorum Vote] = Case
WHEN [number_of_quorum_votes] =1
    THEN 'Yes'
    ELSE 'No '
END
FROM [master].[sys].[dm_hadr_cluster_members]"
$queries += "SELECT primary_replica FROM sys.dm_hadr_availability_group_states;"

Run-Query -queries $queries
```

Comment: For help with your PowerShell code: show your PowerShell code. Most likely you just have an issue with PowerShell's default formatter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/q/31441054/1630171](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31441054/1630171).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I solved this problem by using pipeline for each result. Inside each loop $results | out-string or $results | select *

Btw, how can I mark my question as resolved?